# How can I access the different classes after I did a classification in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification

So I ran a Classification with Google Earth Engine, classifying forest and non-forest. After I prepared my ROI and declared some training points for each forest and non-forest (saved in the variable newfc) I ran the randomForest classification.
The result is okay but my question now is if can access the variable classified to e.g. mask only the area that was classified as forest. I tried several things but can't find a solution for my problem.

Code:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2015-02-01', '2015-12-01')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 1));

var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']
var composite = coll.mosaic(); 
var img = composite.clip(roi);

var newfc = forest.merge(no_forest);

var training = img.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: newfc,
  properties: ['class'],
  scale: 30
});

var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: bands
});

var classified = img.select(bands).classify(classifier);

Map.addLayer(classified, {min:0, max: 1, palette: ['green', 'black']}, 'Forest-Classification');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you need to keep only pixels in class n°1, which are for forest:

```js
var forest_mask = classified.select('classification').eq(1)
var forest = img.updateMask(forest_mask)

Map.addLayer(forest, {bands:['B4','B3','B2'], min:0, max:0.3}, 'Forest')
```

Comment: Dear Rodrigo, I see your point, but I believe that what Kai asked is how can one apply a list of conditions to mask in the ee.Imagem().eq function. Something like:. 

var forest_mask = classified.select('classification').eq([1,3,5,11,etc.])